# Bootstrap how to add help block in multiple fields form group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I have the following code in my Bootstrap form:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Width / Height</label>
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Width" value="" required>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Height" value="" required>
   </div>
   <span class="help-block"><small>A block of help text that breaks onto a new line and may extend beyond one line.</small></span>
</div>
```

The output is this:

[image]

And I would like to get something like this:

[image]

> Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
      <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Width / Height</label>
  <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left:0">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Width" value="Width" required>
  </div>

 <div class="col-md-4">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Height" value="Height" required>
 </div><div class="clearfix"></div>
 <div class="col-md-3">&nbsp</div>
 <span class="help-block"><small>A block of help text that breaks onto a new line and may extend beyond one line.</small></span>
 </div>
```